# How do I display HTML as plain text in a JTree?

Tags: java, html, swing, jtree

**Problem**:  The content of the leaf nodes of my tree is HTML, but I don't want them rendered as HTML.

Many Swing components can include snippets of HTML in order to change how they are rendered.  This includes the nodes of a `JTree`:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode myLeafNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>");
```

If this node is added to the `DefaultTreeModel`, and the model to the `JTree`, it will render the content as HTML.

How do I prevent this?  How do I force it to be rendered as plain text?

**Edit**:  @David Wallace's answer (see below) works.  Here's how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you want the HTML source to be displayed?  Or are you just saying you want it displayed unformatted (as if the tags and so on weren't there)?

Comment: I want to display the source.  I want to see the entire String, including the tags.

Comment: By using HTML entities? `&lt;html&gt;`?

Comment: @Mr.Alien and I tried the HTML entities idea--it's a novel approach--but unfortunately that didn't work.  The entities were rendered as plain text instead of as entities.  The resulting output was not very pretty.

Comment: That's because in Mr. Alien's answer, the beginning of the `String` was no longer `"<html>"` - and that's what Swing uses to decide how to display it.

Comment: Apart from @DavidWallace's correct answer there is a dirty little trick: You can put something at the start of the string before the `<html>`, e.g. a space. Of course this changes the alignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `StringEscapeUtils` class from the Apache Commons library, to escape your HTML, then put it inside `<html><body>` to tell Swing to display the result as HTML.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

String escapedHtml = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(htmlToDisplay); 
DefaultMutableTreeNode myLeafNode = 
    new DefaultMutableTreeNode("<html><body>" + escapedHtml + "</body></html>");
```